# Modify Cloud Trace Sampling Rate for Cloud Run

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-trace

I am running NodeJS code in Cloud Run, via Firebase functions (v2). I am tracing my functions using OpenTelemetry and exporting to Cloud Trace.

I understand from the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/trace)

> Cloud Run doesn't sample the traces for every request. When used with Cloud Run, requests are sampled at a maximum rate of 0.1 requests per second for each instance. You can also force a particular request to be traced.

Some of my Cloud Run services are called significantly more than others. So I'd like to sample requests to infrequently called services at a much higher rate than those that get many requests per second. I am happy with maximum sampling rate being 0.1, I am asking specifically in the range `0 <= sample rate <= 0.1`.

How can I (if possible) modify this sample rate on a per-service basis?